# SQl Server 2012 Date format not recognized from Access 2007

Tags: sql-server, datepicker, ms-access-2007, date-format, data-migration

I have a SQL Server 2012 database with an Access 2007 front-end. My problem is that Access does not recognise SQL Server's dates as they are in a different format.

- SQL Server-s format is `YYYY-MM-DD`
- Access' format is `DD-MM-YYYY`

When the date is displayed in a text-box, it is displayed as a string (without the little calendar icon next to it).
Is there anyway I can configure my Access front-end so that it recognises SQL Server's dates?

I used Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant for Access to migrate the data into SQL Server

As this DB is in development I have the SQL Server on my local machine in C drive (no virtual drives)

From my research I have found this answer:

The problem the user has encountered is with a Driver. Microsoft has a new DLL that must be put on a client 
workstation (or server in the case of Citrix). Once that is done, all the dates in MS Access will work 
properly. My lastest experience with Access 2010 was exactly the same as Access 2003. 
It required a DLL. From there, investigate using a DNS-Less connection string

Where would I find this DDL driver and how would I install it.

Thanks
Maggs

Comment: are you storing date as `DATETIME` or as `VARCHAR` in SQL? If it is DATETIME, you should have no problem metween `DATETIME` in SQL and ACCESS. SQL Server does not stores format, the only reason why it displays date in one way or the other is based on your SQL-Server setting.

Comment: Further to what @SaUce asked, please indicate the *actual* column type in SQL Server. `datetime` columns in SQL Server should show up as `Date/Time` fields in Access. Other SQL Server column types like `date` and `time` usually appear in Access as text values (because Access does not have field types that are just `Date` or `Time`).

Comment: Also: **(1)** If you can provide the link to the article you quoted in your question regarding the DLL "fix" please edit your question to include it. **(2)** Was the updated DLL something that changed the behaviour of Access (or ODBC), or was it something that changed the behaviour of the SQL Server Migration Assistant?

Comment: Hi I do a work round. When data is imported it starts of as a date in access and ends up as a dataTime2 when migrating to SQL Server. I then copy the contents to another column which has a data type date in in international date format. In access it shows up as dateTime in international format. If I don't have to copy the data to another column that would be easier.                                          thanks :-)

Comment: Hi I will try to find that answer and link it. Thanks for your suggestions and help  maggs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that SSMA for some reason converted all the datetimes to datetime2. I went into SQL Server Management Studio and changed them to datetimes and it fixed the issue. You could also check the field mapping in SSMA and adjust it before migrating.

(I have the exact same environment - SQL Server 2012 and Access 2007, using SSMA.)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I think it does answer the question of how to resolve the issue of Access 2007 not recognizing dates after migrating to SQL Server 2012 with SSMA. Is that not the basic issue?

Comment: your reply has helped and is the basic issue. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am using SQL Server 2012 on my local PC (Vista) and have an Access 2010 frontend with ~75 linked tables.
The table in SQL Server has a column named 'EnteredDate' that is defined as 'datetime'.
In Access the 'EnteredDate'column is defined as 'Date/Time'.
In Access, I just ran the following query with proper results:

```
SELECT DataError.Description, DataError.EnteredDate
```

FROM DataError
WHERE (((DataError.EnteredDate) Between #1/1/2010# And #1/31/2010#));

Comment: Hi Wayne thanks for your response. I am able to run queries but it when I get to the form that I have the problem of the the date picker not showing and the date appearing as international format dateTime thanks maggs

Comment: OK, since I can see the date picker on my form (using either continuous or datasheet format), we have a difference. Yes, in SQL Server my date looks like: 2010-02-24; In Access it appears as 2/24/2010, Please check Access column and insure it is 'Date/Time'. I've got to ask if Access is linked directly to the table, or thru a VIEW?